# How to use jq to turning mixed JSON into CSV

Tags: json, csv, jq

can't figure this one out... I want to collapse this JSON so that just the NAME field and the values of DATACLASSES of each record are output to a CSV file.  It's taxing my jq-fu as it has to mix a string with a nested array and somehow get it into a CSV.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Evite",
    "Title": "Evite",
    "Domain": "evite.com",
    "BreachDate": "2013-08-11",
    "AddedDate": "2019-07-14T14:51:51Z",
    "ModifiedDate": "2019-07-14T14:51:51Z",
    "PwnCount": 100985047,
    "Description": "In April 2019, the social planning website for managing online invitations <a href=\"https://www.evite.com/security/update?usource=lc&lctid=1800182\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">Evite identified a data breach of their systems</a>. Upon investigation, they found unauthorised access to a database archive dating back to 2013. The exposed data included a total of 101 million unique email addresses, most belonging to recipients of invitations. Members of the service also had names, phone numbers, physical addresses, dates of birth, genders and passwords stored in plain text exposed. The data was provided to HIBP by a source who requested it be attributed to &quot;JimScott.Sec@protonmail.com&quot;.",
    "LogoPath": "https://haveibeenpwned.com/Content/Images/PwnedLogos/Evite.png",
    "DataClasses": [
      "Dates of birth",
      "Email addresses",
      "Genders",
      "Names",
      "Passwords",
      "Phone numbers",
      "Physical addresses"
    ],
    "IsVerified": true,
    "IsFabricated": false,
    "IsSensitive": false,
    "IsRetired": false,
    "IsSpamList": false
  },
  {
    "Name": "VerificationsIO",
    "Title": "Verifications.io",
    "Domain": "verifications.io",
    "BreachDate": "2019-02-25",
    "AddedDate": "2019-03-09T19:29:54Z",
    "ModifiedDate": "2019-03-09T20:49:51Z",
    "PwnCount": 763117241,
    "Description": "In February 2019, the email address validation service <a href=\"https://securitydiscovery.com/800-million-emails-leaked-online-by-email-verification-service\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">verifications.io suffered a data breach</a>. Discovered by <a href=\"https://twitter.com/mayhemdayone\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">Bob Diachenko</a> and <a href=\"https://twitter.com/vinnytroia\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">Vinny Troia</a>, the breach was due to the data being stored in a MongoDB instance left publicly facing without a password and resulted in 763 million unique email addresses being exposed. Many records within the data also included additional personal attributes such as names, phone numbers, IP addresses, dates of birth and genders. No passwords were included in the data. The Verifications.io website went offline during the disclosure process, although <a href=\"https://web.archive.org/web/20190227230352/https://verifications.io/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">an archived copy remains viewable</a>.",
    "LogoPath": "https://haveibeenpwned.com/Content/Images/PwnedLogos/VerificationsIO.png",
    "DataClasses": [
      "Dates of birth",
      "Email addresses",
      "Employers",
      "Genders",
      "Geographic locations",
      "IP addresses",
      "Job titles",
      "Names",
      "Phone numbers",
      "Physical addresses"
    ],
    "IsVerified": true,
    "IsFabricated": false,
    "IsSensitive": false,
    "IsRetired": false,
    "IsSpamList": false
  }
]
```

I can flatten out DataClasses only with this jq pipeline:

```
jq -r  '.[] | {DataClasses} | .[] | @csv'
```

But it's missing the name string and I have not been able to puzzle out how to include it.

The context is to generate a report from haveibeenpwned.com (where the JSON is returned from) that will contain the breach name and details from the DataClasses as to the nature of the breach so it can be nicely summarized and notifications emailed to affected parties. Easy enough to script this -- We have the API key, etc, but can't quite figure out how to get the JSON to cooperate ;)

If this basic approach of having it all in a CSV (where it can be easily mangled in perl or python), any suggestions on how best handle it elegantly via jq mangling that will allow us to easily reference the NAME of the breach and the items in its associated DATACLASSES array would be most helpful

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank-you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sample JSON, the invocation

```
jq -r '.[] | [.Name, .DataClasses[]] | @csv'
```

produces:

```
"Evite","Dates of birth","Email addresses","Genders","Names","Passwords","Phone numbers","Physical addresses"
"VerificationsIO","Dates of birth","Email addresses","Employers","Genders","Geographic locations","IP addresses","Job titles","Names","Phone numbers","Physical addresses"
```